# Deleting the first two lines of a file using BASH or awk or sed or whatever

Tags: bash, awk, sed, lines

I'm trying to delete the first two lines of a file by just not printing it to another file.  I'm not looking for something fancy. Here's my (failed) attempt at awk:

```
awk '{ (NR > 2) {print} }' myfile
```

That throws out the following error:

```
awk: { NR > 2 {print} }
awk:          ^ syntax error
```

Example:

contents of 'myfile':

```
blah
blahsdfsj
1 
2
3
4
```

What I want the result to be:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use tail:

```
tail -n+3 file
```

from the man page:

```
   -n, --lines=K
          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use  -n  +K
          to output lines starting with the Kth
```

Answer (score 31):

How about:

```
tail +3 file
```

OR

```
awk 'NR>2' file
```

OR

```
sed '1,2d' file
```

Comment: Another variant of sed: `sed -n '3,$p' file`

Answer (score 26):

You're nearly there. Try this instead:

```
awk 'NR > 2 { print }' myfile
```

awk is rule based, and the rule appears bare (i.e., without braces) before the block it woud execute if it passes.

Also as Jaypal has pointed out, in awk if all you want to do is print the line that matches the rules you can even omit the action, thus simplifying the command to:

```
awk 'NR > 2' myfile
```

Comment: He could also put an `if` before parentheses, though your way is better, since it doesn't engage every line, just the ones that already match.

Comment: You dont even need `{ print }`. `awkish` way would be `awk 'NR>2' myfile`

Answer (score 6):

`awk` is based on `pattern{action}` statements. In your case, the `pattern` is `NR>2` and the `action` you want to perform is `print`. This `action` is also the **`default action`** of `awk`.

So even though

`awk 'NR>2{print}' filename`

would work fine, you can shorten it to

`awk 'NR>2' filename`.