# Linux system utilization import in PostgreSQL Database

Tags: linux, postgresql, redhat

I want to import the daily Linux system utilization file in PostgreSQL Database.

```
# ls /var/log/sa
sar -f sa13 >>/tmp/test_clean.csv
```

I am able to generate a .csv file using above command, but this format is allowing me to import into PostgreSQL database.

```
root#> less /tmp/test_clean.csv
<Linux redhat version> (servername)      <date>      _x86_64_        (2 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all      0.10      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.83
12:20:01 AM     all      0.12      0.00      0.06      0.02      0.00     99.80
12:30:01 AM     all      0.08      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.85
12:40:01 AM     all      0.06      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.88
12:50:01 AM     all      0.07      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.86
01:00:01 AM     all      0.09      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.84
01:10:01 AM     all      0.07      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.86
```

Any Solution..!!

Comment: this is not a csv file, please update the question to show the format of the file as it really is, providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working Answer:

1. Use the below command to create a .csv file.

   ```
   sadf -dh -- -p| tr ';' ','| awk 'NR>1{print $0}' > /tmp/test_clean.csv
   ```
2. Then, create the table

   ```
   CREATE TABLE system_utilzation (
        hostname  text,
        interval  text,
        ts       TIME,
        cpu      TEXT,
        users     NUMERIC,
        nice     NUMERIC,
        system     NUMERIC,
        iowait      NUMERIC, 
        steal      NUMERIC,
        idle     NUMERIC
       );
   ```
3. Create a temp table using below command.

   ```
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_system_utilzation AS SELECT * FROM system_utilzation WHERE 1=2;
   ```
4. Import data from .csv file to table.

   ```
   copy temp_system_utilzation from '/tmp/test_clean.csv' with CSV HEADER;
   ```
5. Then insert data into main table called ***system_utilzation***

   ```
   INSERT INTO system_utilzation SELECT * FROM temp_system_utilzation;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to clean the file from the first two lines:
then you will a create a table.
finally, you will insert into the table.

There are [a few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857705/deleting-the-first-two-lines-of-a-file-using-bash-or-awk-or-sed-or-whatever) to clean the file, but you can run something like

```
cat /tmp/test.csv|awk 'NR>2' > /tmp/test_clean.csv
```

Then you'll need to create a table:
The [syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html) is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE system_utilzation (
    ts       TIME,
    cpu      TEXT,
    user     NUMERIC,
    nice     NUMERIC,
    system     NUMERIC,
    iowait      NUMERIC, 
    steal      NUMERIC,
    idle     NUMERIC
);
```

Inserting a CSV file into your table can be done using `COPY` or `\COPY` if this the first time you are populating the table. if you want this to run as routine job, you'll want to `[INSERT][3]` it.

You can do that using an empty temp table. the temp table is unique per connection and will be automatically deleted after you disconnect from Posgres:
`CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_system_utilzation AS SELECT * FROM system_utilzation WHERE 1=2;`
then you will populate it using `psql` and `\COPY`.

```
psql -h remotehost -d remote_mydb -U myuser -c "\copy temp_system_utilzation from '/tmp/test_clean.csv' with CSV HEADER"
```

Lastly, you can insert from your temp table into the full table using something like this:
`INSERT INTO ystem_utilzation SELECT * FROM temp_system_utilzation;`

Comment: demo=# copy temp_system_utilzation from '/tmp/test_clean.csv' with CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "12:10:01 AM     all      0.10      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.83"
CONTEXT:  COPY temp_system_utilzation, line 2, column ts: "12:10:01 AM     all      0.10      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.83"
demo=#

Comment: better change it from `timestamp` to `time`

Comment: this probably means you don't have a csv file.
try to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348914/output-sar-command-results-to-a-csv-file to make sure you have a csv file as you may have a file with spaces instead.

Comment: something like this should work `sadf -dh -- -p| tr ';' ','| awk 'NR>3{print $0}'`

Comment: Thanks its working for me but in CPU column it showing -1 instead of all.

Comment: please update the question to include the file in CSV format